# jQuery effect after ajax-page-load doesn't take place

Tags: jquery

I'm working on my new site and I stumble upon a silly problem I can't figure out a solution for. The concept is located at [www.ontdek5.nl/index.php](http://www.ontdek5.nl/index.php). When you enter the page my subtile jQuery effects 'slide together' the page. From the navigation the user should be able to browse through the different pages where only the contentpart should reload. Currently this works but the jQuery effects aren't executed.

How can I achieve a jQuery effect to run when a user clicks a different menu-item? I would like to clip-in the content columns but this now only happens on the initial page-load.

Comment: You look like you are quite proficient in jQuery so may I ask why you are still using "old-school" AJAX? You could be running all those "animations" in the callback function after you AJAX GET

Comment: Because I wanted some quick results to see how it 'flows' and I have the 'old-school-ajax' as predefined codesnippets in my IDE :) Thanks for the compliment though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Like "The_Butcher" said,

> You could be running all those "animations" in the callback function after you AJAX GET

jQuery has a nice set of functions for that ([$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)).  Each of jQuery's AJAX functions include an optional callback on success, which would be where you'd put your HTML loading code.  Here's a code example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //use the jQuery ajax function to get your HTML
  $.get({
    dataType: "html",
    url: "ajax.ServePage.php?pageID=" + pageID,
    success: successFunction,
    error: errorFunction,
  });
});

function successFunction(data, textStatus, xmlHttpResponse) {
  //code to update your HTML
  $("body").html(data);
}

function errorFunction(xmlHttpResponse, textStatus) {
  alert("Data load error");
}
```

The jQuery documentation is quite good if you want more information.

Comment: Would you rather see this in vanilla JavaScript or are you looking for something else?